# Does the splitting field of an irreducible polynomial contain all extensions over which the polynomial factors?

Tags: field-theory, splitting-field

Say $f$ is an irreducible polynomial with coefficients in a field $F$.
Say $f$ is no longer irreducible over some extension $K$ of $f$, i.e. $f$ factors into a product of (irreducible) polynomials having degree $\geq 0$. Does the splitting field $E$ of $f$ over $F$ necessarily contain $K$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The splitting field contains every field extension that is generated by adjoining roots of $f$.

It does, of course, not contain *every*  field extension over which $f$ factors. To see this for example take a proper field extension of the splitting field. Clearly $f$ factors there while it is not contained in the splitting field.

Comment: More properly, the splitting field contains an *isomorphic copy* of every field extension that is generated by adjoining roots of $f$.

Comment: Yes. Or, which is what I implicitly assumed, we work with a fixed algebraic closure. (Otherwise there is not "the splitting field" to begin with.)